# sh: d2j-dex2jar.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, osx

I'm trying to use `dex2jar` to extract a `.jar` file from my `.apk`.

I have downloaded this version: https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar

And followed the instuctions:

```
sh d2j-dex2jar.sh -f ~/path/to/apk_to_decompile.apk
```

however I get `sh: d2j-dex2jar.sh: No such file or directory` - which is true, there's no file or directory named `d2j-dex2jar.sh` in the downloaded `dex2jar-2.x` directory.

I performed that command: `sh d2j-dex2jar.sh -f ~/path/to/apk_to_decompile.apk` inside of the dex2jar directory.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Looks to me like this is the source code, and the developer has completely forgoten to mention how to build it. Probably with gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you point to is source code. You can get the build executable code from https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar/releases **version 2.0 is the latest stable build**.

I clicked the releases tab at the top, of the page.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Although I still don't understand what the difference is? - I thought build executable code is classified as source code...what's the point of the initial one I downloaded?

Comment: Source code is the source, it is what we write. It is human readable. It gets compiled into executable code. Sometimes (for example python), there is no difference. The purpose of what you, initially, downloaded, is for people to modify the code, before compiling.